# five column grid not scaling down correctly

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, grid-layout

I'm using a fluid grid with a max-width of 1280px.
Min-width of the grid is 950px,

In my example I use 3 different grid sizes - grid6, grid8 and grid12.
There is also a grid16 and grid24, these are not used in this example though.

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmL7A/

When scaling down the browser window the smallest grid (grid6) is not equal in height to the rest of the grids. Grid6 gets smaller than the other grid-sizes in height.

Has anyone experienced this before and is there a solution for this without using media-queries?

```
.grid6_asset,
.grid8_asset,
.grid12_asset,
.grid16_asset{ 
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.grid6_asset{
    width:20%;
}
.grid8_asset{
    width:40%;
}
.grid12_asset{
    width:60%;
}
.grid16_asset{
    width:80%;
}
.grid24_asset{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Well `grid6` has just `20%` width and rest are wider than that.. when page size changes all div's width will scale up or down accordingly.. anyways `40%` always be greater than `20%`.. what else do you expect..?!!

Comment: I don't know if it was me who explained it wrong or if you misunderstood?

Did you check out my fiddle?

I am well aware that 40% is greater than 20%, but the height of the grids used in my example will differ, when scaling down. eventhough they should have the same height.

Comment: when scaling the window down to 950px, there would be a variation of 3 pixels in height.

Comment: Your question said `grid6` is smaller than the other grids, it didn't mention anything about `height`, you added it in an edit 1 hour after my comment. lol

Answer (score 1):

If you set either `width` or `height` for an image, the other property will be calculated automatically according to the aspect ratio. In your fiddle, all images have same `height`, but they differ in `width`. So if you set it's the width and leave height, height will be automatically calculated and since `width` and aspect ratio of the images are different, calculated `height` will also differ.

If you set the height of the images, then the height will be same regardless of the window size but width will be calculated automatically and will differ with respect to aspect ratio as in this  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/dmL7A/3/).

If you set both height and width explicitly , then the aspect ratio will be compromised.

Comment: When scaling it down, the grids is overflowing each other and is not scaling down.
I would like the whole grid to scale down and the height of the grids should be the same when scaling down.

Comment: If you keep the height as same, and reduce the width according to window size, then obviously the aspect ratio of the image will change.. is that fine..?

Comment: it should be as in the fiddle I made, where the whole grid is scaling, but there is a bug in this one.
When scaling to min-width of 950px the grid6 gets 3px smaller in height than the rest.
So I don't think setting a height would make the whole grid scaleable.